# React Server Components (RSC) with Supabase Auth: UI not updating after login/logout

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I'm working on a Next.js application using React Server Components (RSC), and I've integrated Supabase for authentication and database functionality. However, I'm facing an issue where the UI does not update after a successful login or logout action unless I manually reload the page.

I have two main components in my application:
Navbar.tsx (Server Component):

- This component is responsible for rendering the main navigation bar.
  It uses the createServerComponentClient from @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs to fetch the session.

user-btn.tsx (Client Component):

- This component handles user authentication and profile display.
  It uses the createClientComponentClient from @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs to interact with Supabase for authentication and data fetching.

The problem occurs when I successfully log in or log out. The UI does not update to reflect the new session state until I manually reload the page. This behavior is not ideal as it should update in real-time without a manual page reload.

I've tried using router.refresh() from next/navigation to force a page refresh after login/logout actions in the user-btn.tsx component. While this works to some extent, it feels like a workaround, and it's not the ideal user experience.

What is the best practice for handling UI updates in React Server Components (RSC) when using authentication with Supabase? How can I ensure that the UI updates immediately after a successful login or logout action without the need for manual page reloading?

Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve real-time UI updates with RSC and Supabase would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
// navbar.tsx
import { cookies } from "next/headers"
import Link from "next/link"
import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"

import { Database } from "@/types/supabase"
import { UserAccount } from "./user-btn"

export const Navbar = async () => {
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient<Database>({ cookies })
    const {
        data: { session },
    } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

    return (
        <header className="top-0 z-40 w-full border-b bg-background">
            <div className="container flex h-16 items-center space-x-4 sm:justify-between sm:space-x-0">
                <div className="flex gap-6 md:gap-10">
                    <Link href="/" className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                        <span className="inline-block font-bold">Certify</span>
                    </Link>
                </div>

                <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-end">
                    <nav className="flex items-center">
                        <UserAccount session={session} />
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}
```

```
// user-btn.tsx
"use client"

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Link from "next/link"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import {
    createClientComponentClient,
    Session,
} from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"

import { Database } from "@/types/supabase"
import { Avatar, AvatarFallback, AvatarImage } from "@/components/ui/avatar"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownMenuContent,
    DropdownMenuGroup,
    DropdownMenuItem,
    DropdownMenuLabel,
    DropdownMenuSeparator,
    DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu"

export const UserAccount = ({ session }: { session: Session | null }) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string | null>(null)
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState<string | null>(null)
    const [avatar_url, setAvatarUrl] = useState<string | null>(null)

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({ provider: "google" })
        router.refresh()
    }

    const handleLogOut = async () => {
        await supabase.auth.signOut()
        router.refresh()
    }

    const getProfile = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true)

            let { data, error, status } = await supabase
                .from("student")
                .select("*")
                .eq("id", session?.user.id ?? "")
                .single()

            if (error && status !== 406) {
                throw error
            }

            if (data) {
                setFirstName(data.first_name)
                setLastName(data.last_name)
                setAvatarUrl(data.avatar_url)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProfile()
    }, [session, getProfile])

    return session ? (
        <>
            <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
                    <Button
                        variant={"ghost"}
                        className="relative h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                    >
                        <Avatar>
                            <AvatarImage src={avatar_url ?? ""} />
                        </Avatar>
                    </Button>
                </DropdownMenuTrigger>
                <DropdownMenuContent
                    className="w-56 mt-2"
                    align="end"
                    forceMount
                >
                    <DropdownMenuLabel className="font-normal">
                        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1">
                            <p className="text-sm font-medium leading-none">
                                {firstName + " " + lastName}
                            </p>
                            <p className="text-xs leading-none text-muted-foreground">
                                {session.user.email}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </DropdownMenuLabel>
                    <DropdownMenuSeparator />
                    <DropdownMenuGroup>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link
                                className="text-center w-full"
                                href={"/account"}
                            >
                                Settings
                            </Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuSeparator />
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Button
                                onClick={handleLogOut}
                                variant={"destructive"}
                                className="w-full"
                            >
                                Log Out
                            </Button>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                    </DropdownMenuGroup>
                </DropdownMenuContent>
            </DropdownMenu>
        </>
    ) : (
        <Button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please see the documentation for the recommended approach with Next.js: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#server-side